# Two dismissals off a single ball

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

1. Is it possible to dismiss both batsmen off the same delivery (i.e., by a catch and a run out)?
2. If the ball touched the lower end of the bat, edged up and touched the bat again, will it be given out? This is assuming that the batsman does not intend to hit it twice.
3. If the ball hits the bat on the other side of the bat, does it count as a dismissal?

[image]

Comment: The answers given below are correct with respect to only one dismissal being possible off a single delivery. However, note that it is possible to have more than one dismissal before the next delivery is bowled. After a batsman is dismissed, the next batsman might be _timed out_, or the remaining batsman might be dismissed for _obstructing the field_. So one could, theoretically, have both batsman dismissed with only one delivery used up, or even have an entire team dismissed before a single ball is bowled in the match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to dismiss both the batsmen in ground(ie,by a catch and a run out)?

No. It is not possible to dismiss both batsmen on the same delivery. Only one batsman can be legally dismissed. In the event of both being dismissed on the same delivery, the batsman dismissed first goes back to the pavilion while the other continues with his/her innings.

> Is "Hit the ball twice" out?

According to the Laws of Cricket (Law 34 - as stated below), if done intentionally, then yes, it is out.

> **Law 34 (Hit the ball twice)**
>   1. Out Hit the ball twice
>
> - The striker is out Hit the ball twice if, while the ball is in play, it strikes any part of his person or is struck by his bat and, before the ball has been touched by a fielder, he willfully strikes it again with his bat or person, other than a hand not holding the bat, except for the sole purpose of guarding his wicket. See 3 below and Laws 33 (Handled the ball) and 37 (Obstructing the field).
> - For the purpose of this Law, 'struck' or 'strike' shall include contact with the person of the striker.

However, as with any potential dismissal, the batsman can still continue his/her innings in the following cases:

1. The opposition team does not appeal ([Law 27.1](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-27-appeals/)).
2. The appeal is withdrawn by the opposition captain and the umpire consents to the withdrawal, before the batsman leaves the field of play ([Law 27.8](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-27-appeals/)).

> Is it considered a dismissal if the ball hits the other side of the bat?

No. As of the current laws, this does not constitute a dismissal. However, the way the modern bat is designed, the batsmen do not get any advantage by using the other side of the bat. So, it does not make sense for the batsmen to use the other side of the bat.

Comment: In addition to the @Orangecrush answer for the third question **Is it considered a dismissal if the ball hits the other side of the bat?** i think there is a reference of Sri Lanka's Mahela Jayawardene Playing with the other side of the bat in a cricket match against India.But i am not able to find out the link for it to prove.But still i found this video of David Warner http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PY2vUSYH_jw

Comment: I disagree - if you stretch the limit, you can have both batsmen run out, you can have a batsman out normally and the next timed out, and theoretically there is nothing to stop both batsmen being out obstructing the field either

Answer (score 8):

1. No, because the ball becomes dead when a (that is, the first) dismissal occurs.
2. If it is not intentional, then it is not out.  (Note the term "willful" in Law 34.)
3. Touching the back of the bat is by itself not a reason for a dismissal.  But the back does count as part of the bat for purposes of caught etc.

Answer (score 6):

1) Definitely not - in addition you cannot run out both batsmen - once one is run out, or a batsman is out by any means, the ball is dead and no further wickets can take place on that ball (neither can runs be scored).

2) No.  If the batsman is deemed to have intentionally hit the ball twice, AND the opposing team appeals AND he is given out AND the opposing captain does not call him back, then he is out having hit the ball twice.

3) Nope, accidents happen - eg trying to sweep the ball and having it hit the back.  Inevitably this is not optimal - due to the shape on the back it often skies giving the opposing team a catch.  Perhaps if bat designs change and it becomes useful to do this, then it may change, but as of now, you can hit the ball with any side of the bat.

EDIT

Now that I work in the cricket arena, I can say it's possible, especially in last man standing types of formats.  Also you can be timed out/absent if you don't enter the field within the requisite amount of time, so then two batsmen would certainly be out on the same ball.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways a batting team can lose a wicket during a dead-ball situation (as is the case immediately after losing a wicket), for example a batsman may **retire out**. The batsman in question generally cannot return to the field (though a batsman could retire and then return with the permission of the opposing captain) and thus the batting team would be down to 10 men. If this occurs between one wicket and the next ball, they've effectively lost two wickets on one ball. The second way I can think of is that any batsman who is **timed out** (fails to appear on the pitch in a timely manner)—unless they are in the opening pair—is of course following on from another loss of wicket before the next ball has been bowled. Therefore the team has again lost two wickets with only one ball being bowled. Neither of these, though, are cases of the fielding team taking two wickets from one ball.